# Loop in WordPress theme that show only tagged articles, don't work

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am new in PHP and in WordPress world and I having a problem with the creation of a loop that show only the post having a specific tag.

In homepage I would create a loop that show me only the articles that have setted a specific tag, so I have implement the following PHP loop for wordpress:

```
   <div id="column2">
        <?php   
            query_posts( 'tag=sasha' );  
            if(have_posts()): 
                while (have_posts()): the_post(); 
        ?>  

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>  
        <?php endif; ?> 
   </div> <!-- end column2 -->
```

I have an article in which I have setted a tag as: sasha

The problem is that don't work and my column2 div still remain empty. Why? Can you help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: please do not use **query_posts** use wp_query instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should look for you when using `WP_QUERY`:

```
$args = array('tag' => 'sasha');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
        the_content();
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: try with out the tag, also post the code that the loop sits in such page.php or single.php, etc

Comment: what you means when you say: "out the tag"?

Comment: without the tag, sorry. I mean do not pass a tag to see if it works without sasha

Comment: Passing no tag in this way: $args = array(); (in the index.php page) the columns still remain void !!! :-/

Comment: Ohhh yes, the error was mine because I left the if statment present in the previous snippet (not your !!!) LOL